# Flutter: Getting Microphone Data into a Stream and Graphing It

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm trying to build an IOS/Android app that takes periodic snapshots of microphone data and graphs it (ex. every 100ms, a recorded segment of microphone data is graphed). Specifically, it's supposed to be the microphone amplitude vs. time being graphed. I'm also using syncfusion_flutter_charts to graph my data.

I don't know which microphone recording library to use. I've tried flutter_sound and mic_stream but I can't figure out how to get either to work with what I'm trying to do. I'm just at a complete loss for getting microphone data and then manipulating it in the way I want.